# Button click event and picker view object firing

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uibutton, picker

I need to know how to firing picker object after I click a button. So i need to know how to do that one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented **UIPickerViewDelegate**  **didSelectRow** delegate method,

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Comment: do i need to added anything to method called - (IBAction)pickkerBtnClick:(id)sender {
     
}

Comment: @Gayan J : Do you have above mentioned function (didSelectRow ) in your code ?

Comment: I just start a new project and add button and picker.. now I hide picker. i can se button only. So I need to fire picker after I click buton. So how can i do it. ??

Comment: @Gayan J :Do you get your button action method called on click ? if yes you could hide your picker view by putting the statement myPickerView.hidden = YES ; in your button action method.

Comment: Oki.. thanks for your help. by the way.. how can I firing picker object in animated way ?? for this code picker will come out like a rock.. :D (I need to show it just like navigation to windows to windows like animated way..  )